# What does the cloud icon with lines underneath mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, weather.app

In the iOS Weather app what does the cloud icon with two horizontal lines beneath mean?

[image: screenshot of weather app showing icon I question]

Answer (score 6):

It means fog, a list of the icons can be found at [About the Weather app and icons on your iPhone and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207492).

> [image: Screenshot of: About the Weather app and icons on your iPhone and iPod touch from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207492]
>   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207492